# Dataset API -- Variable input sizes for batching

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am training a model that can accept variable input sizes (its a fully convolutional network) that has quite a complex input pipeline.

Thats why i have to use the dataset api's `from_generator` method to handle all the logic.

However, I want to be able to train the network on image batches of different sizes. 
E.g. for first batch, the input images may be of size 200x200 , but for the next one it may be 300x300.

I want to randomise this process for a variety of size ranges (e.g. from 100x100 to 2000x2000).

This would be quite trivial using feed_dict: i would prepare a batch with the specific image size on each train step.

Is there any way to do this using the (high performance) dataset api so that I can leverage multi threading/prefetching without much work ?

Comment: not sure why i was down voted. reasons would be welcome so that I may improve my questin

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to start with Datasets for each different minibatch size you want to support, do batching within each such dataset, and then interleave them before building an iterator.

Comment: I was thinking of changing the input size inside the generator randomly , say every 100 steps. since there could be unequal input sizes due to multi thread calls, i was hoping to just run my train look in a try catch block (and ignore that error of unequal input dimensions)

Comment: That will work but will do a lot of unnecessary I/O and hence might not scale very well to many GPUs, but it will work at first.

Comment: why will it do unnecessary IO ? i believe only the batch where the exception will be thrown will be wasted? Or does this logic introduce additional wasted IO ?

Comment: every time you ignore the error of unequal input dimensions that's a bunch of I/O you did which will not turn into a minibatch